# Reading a list of URLs into a Python list

Tags: python-2.7

I am a newbie in Python and I wish to read a list of URLs into a Python list. Below is my script :

```
if __name__ == 'main' :
    urls_list = [] #Creating the URL vector

    with open('url_list.doc') as my_file :
        for line in my_file :
            urls_list.append(line)

    print (urls_list)
```

The above code does not generate any output or error even. Below is **url_list.doc** :

```
https://www.nytimes.com/2017/03/03/us/politics/majority-rule-means-the-power-to-stop-not-just-start-an-investigation.html
https://www.nytimes.com/2017/03/03/business/retirement/millennials-ask-elders-about-retirement.html?hp&action=click&pgtype=Homepage&clickSource=story-heading&module=photo-spot-region&region=top-news&WT.nav=top-news
https://www.nytimes.com/2017/03/02/us/politics/jeff-sessions-russia-trump-investigation-democrats.html?hp&action=click&pgtype=Homepage&clickSource=story-heading&module=first-column-region&region=top-news&WT.nav=top-news
https://www.nytimes.com/2017/03/02/business/trump-pentagon-budget.html?hp&action=click&pgtype=Homepage&clickSource=story-heading&module=first-column-region&region=top-news&WT.nav=top-news
https://www.nytimes.com/2017/03/03/style/modern-love-you-may-want-to-marry-my-husband.html?hp&action=click&pgtype=Homepage&clickSource=story-heading&module=second-column-region&region=top-news&WT.nav=top-news
```

Any suggestions on how to perform this.

Comment: Is `url_list.doc` a text file that is poorly named or an MS Word document?

Comment: Change `'main'` to `'__main__'`

Comment: This is just a typo. The code is fine. I recommend closing this question.

Comment: It is an MS word document but what would a poorly named document mean? I mean are you talking about the name or is it something else? @Mad Physicist

Comment: In general, the `.doc` extension is used for Microsoft Word Documents, which are stored in a proprietary binary format. So I am asking if the file is plain text or a word document.

Comment: Either way, the problem is with `main` vs `__main__`.

Comment: Yep a typo, but the output is generating a bunch of x[0-9][0-9]s.

Comment: Then you have a word document most likely. Save the data as an actual text file.

Comment: You're right, thank you! How do I know/learn about how such things make a difference or how do they work?

Comment: Mainly by experience and a lot of reading documentation/asking questions. While I recommend deleting this question, you did the right thing by asking it. Keep doing what you are doing and you will git gud pretty quickly. Besides the typo, that is actually very clean Python code for a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

To parse .doc files you need [Antiword](http://www.winfield.demon.nl/). It is a standalone command line executable so we are going to have to use `Popen` & `PIPE`.

Code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

file_path = "Your file path here"

cmd = ['antiword', file_path]
p = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
text = stdout.decode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

`text` now has all the content of the .doc file.